# How to develop LMS API for SCORM in .NET

Tags: c#, api, scorm, scorm2004

When I am trying to get API object its saying "unable to find LMS API", 
In SCORM_API.js file 'win.API' and 'win.API_1484_11' both objects are undefined.

So here Do I need to write an API (other that scorm_api.js) which will connect to LMS server and client?
How to do that in .net?
Is there any help document available for same?

http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/api-discovery-algorithms/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps if you included the LMS server & client you are using, you might get more responses

Comment: @SimonHalsey: What do you mean by LMS server? Do I need to setup LMS server? I have created one web-application in .net and hosted on server.

Comment: Surely something is hosting the api you're connecting to? Or you writing an LMS server & looking to provide a SCORM api for users to use?

Comment: Yes, I want to write an API which will connect to my LMS DB and client browser to track SCORM progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got excellent tutorial -

http://www.vsscorm.net/2009/05/31/getting-started-the-rte-frameset/#more-22

This helps me lot.

Answer (score 3):

Practical Implementation sources are little bit available for SCORM over the Internet, few may disagree from my point, but I really found it hard while discovering for SCORM2004.

I am sharing my knowledge with you(hopefully someone may add to it to increase the availability of content for the topic).

Basically you will came across 3 things when looking for SCORM.

1. LMS (Learning Management System)
2. RTE (Run Time Environment)
3. SCORM Content or package

LMS can be written in any language(PHP,C#,Ruby etc).

RTE can be consider as a player for playing the SCORM package.

If you have a SCORM package(with the object name I am assuming its on SCORM2004) then in your RTE you need to make sure that this object should be located in a window that is a parent of the SCO or a parent of the opener window of the SCO.

For more reference you can follow http://scorm.com as lot more information available there.

[image: Ostyn]

Image Source - [OSTYN](http://www.ostyn.com/standards/docs/GeneralArchitectureForLMSImplementation-1.htm)

**EDIT**

As per the comment you can create an RTE in C#/PHP etc using the concept -

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>RTE For playing SCORM Package</title>
</head>
<frameset framespacing="0" border="0" rows="0,*">
    <frame src="YOUR_API_FILE.EXTENSION" name="API_1484_11">
    <frame src="YOUR_CONTENT_PATH.EXTENSION" name="course">
</frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah this looks better. My question is how to write RTE and how can it will be available in client browser? any example in c#?

Comment: @Abhi I added a basic demo code here for RTE as per your comment, however your question is asking for API then YES you need to write an API with which data flow controlled and sequencing/navigation is maintained

Answer (score 0):

You essentially want to expose something like:

```
var API_1484_11 = new SCORMRuntimeAPIInstance(); // Your Runtime API
```

Opinion- Framesets are a bit dated at this point, in fact they are obsolete from HTML5.

Long as you've exposed your LMS Runtime API (API for SCORM 1.2) / (API_1484_11 for SCORM 2004).

If you run the content in a popup, new window/tab, or in a IFRAME the SCO will search the DOM (Document Object Model) for this API namespace.  So you need to have this API prepared, the student attempt loaded, then load the Shareable Content Object (SCO).